# Unable to pass textGrob as main to do.call("arrangeGrob")

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, grob

While

```
test <- do.call("arrangeGrob", c(plots.list[1:2],ncol=2,main=("test"))
```

works just fine,

```
test <- do.call("arrangeGrob", c(plots.list[1:2],ncol=2,main=textGrob("test")))
```

gives the following error:

`"Error in arrangeGrob(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1,  :  input must be grobs!"`

I need the main to be a textGrob in order to set font size and font face. Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the list of parameters for `do.call` is not correct,

```
c(list(1, 2), ncol=1, textGrob("a"))
```

"exposes" the contents of textGrob, while you really want to append two lists,

```
c(list(1, 2), list(ncol=1, textGrob("a")))
```

Applied to your question, this becomes

```
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots.list[1:2],list(ncol=2, main=textGrob("test"))))
```

but note that the upcoming version of gridExtra (>= 2.0.0) no longer recognises `main`, you should use `top` instead

```
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots.list[1:2],list(ncol=2, top=textGrob("test"))))
```

and, since `arrangeGrob` gained a new `grobs` argument, you don't need `do.call` anymore,

```
grid.arrange(grobs=plots.list[1:2], ncol=2, top=textGrob("test"))
```

Comment: I tried `arrangeGrob(grobs = plots.list[1:4], ncol = 2)` but stil get the error `input must be grobs!`. `arrangeGrob(plots.list[[1]], plots.list[[2]], plots.list[[3]], plots.list[[4]], ncol=2)` works.  The hint for do.call worked though! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling, I found the answer directly after having posted the question.....

The following works:

```
test <- do.call("grid.arrange",c(plots.list, ncol=2, main =substitute(textGrob("test"),env = parent.frame())))
```